# How to correctly declare/use a TypeVar when a function needs to access a common member (get error: has no attribute...)?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to provide type hints for a function that returns an instance of a class provided as an argument and also *accesses* an element of this class. For example:

```py
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar, Type, TypeVar

@dataclass
class SomeDataClass:

    core_item: str
    PATTERN: ClassVar[str] = r"^([a-z]{3})$"

    def __init__(self, args: tuple[str, ...]) -> None:
        self.core_item = args[0]

@dataclass
class AnotherDataClass:

    core_item: int
    PATTERN: ClassVar[str] = r"^([0-9]{3})$"

    def __init__(self, args: tuple[str, ...]) -> None:
        self.core_item = int(args[0])

Parsable = TypeVar("Parsable", bound=SomeDataClass|AnotherDataClass)

def some_factory(result_type: Type[Parsable], line: str) -> Parsable:
    if not (match := re.match(result_type.PATTERN, line)):
        raise RuntimeError(f"Could not parse {line} with pattern {result_type.PATTERN}")
    return result_type(match.groups())

a = some_factory(SomeDataClass, "abc")
b = some_factory(AnotherDataClass, "123")
```

But MyPy gives me error messages I didn't expect:

```py
worksnt.py:25: error: "Type[Parsable]" has no attribute "PATTERN"  [attr-defined]
worksnt.py:26: error: "Type[Parsable]" has no attribute "PATTERN"  [attr-defined]
worksnt.py:27: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[SomeDataClass, AnotherDataClass]", expected "Parsable")  [return-value]
```

I can "solve" this by providing a `BaseClass` which contains only the shared `PATTERN` element, next to a useless `__init__` function, and binding `Parsable` to `BaseClass` instead of the union of `SomeDataClass` and `AnotherDataClass`:

```py
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import ClassVar, Type, TypeVar, Protocol

class BaseClass(Protocol):  # pylint: disable=too-few-public-methods
    """Why do I need this?"""

    PATTERN: ClassVar[str]

    def __init__(self, args: tuple[str, ...]) -> None:
        """Also needless"""

@dataclass
class SomeDataClass:
    core_item: str
    PATTERN: ClassVar[str] = r"^([a-z]{3})$"

    def __init__(self, args: tuple[str, ...]) -> None:
        self.core_item = args[0]

@dataclass
class AnotherDataClass:
    core_item: int
    PATTERN: ClassVar[str] = r"^([0-9]{3})$"

    def __init__(self, args: tuple[str, ...]) -> None:
        self.core_item = int(args[0])

Parsable = TypeVar("Parsable", bound=BaseClass)

def some_factory(result_type: Type[Parsable], line: str) -> Parsable:
    if not (match := re.match(result_type.PATTERN, line)):
        raise RuntimeError(f"Could not parse {line} with pattern {result_type.PATTERN}")
    return result_type(match.groups())

a = some_factory(SomeDataClass, "abc")
b = some_factory(AnotherDataClass, "123")
```

But why do I have to explicitly explain `PATTERN` with this base class? Shouldn't MyPy infer it from the explicit list of possible classes all of them providing `PATTERN`?

**Update**:
As a colleague pointed out, declaring `bound` to be a union might be an issue.

```
Parsable = TypeVar("Parsable", SomeDataClass, AnotherDataClass)
```

works as expected.
Using a `Protocol` might be the cleaner solution though, I just don't completely understand the problem yet..

Comment: Won't fix your problem, but if you're using a `Protocol` you shouldn't need to inherit from it in the concrete classes - the point of protocol is defining an interface rather than a sub-classing relation

Comment: Here's a better version of the `Protocol` work-around: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=08ba2ea2228609e54abb9cd1309285ce

Comment: It seems a deficiency in mypy that it can't recognise the shared structure in the members of the union. Here's a clue what is wrong: https://mypy-play.net/?gist=f1cafadbe7c5e379e230af6781b056ee&mypy=latest&python=3.11  Note that the `reveal_type` are reported even though the function isn't called. If you uncomment out the calls then the `reveal_type` are reported once despite two function calls. Because mypy doesn't run the code, it's pure static analysis. I think this is somehow related to its inability to resolve the union to one or the other type - the input is a union so the output is too

Comment: Here's an alternative work-around using `@overload`: https://mypy-play.net/?gist=aa4523e11bd2b2ace593945f1aaefb2d&mypy=latest&python=3.11

Comment: @Anentropic - that's true of course, I came from a non-Protocol-class and forgot to remove it

Comment: ah, the `TypeVar` edit/update you made is nicer than the `@overload` :)

Comment: Pyright is happy with your first sample, so it's a `mypy` bug. Please consider reporting it at [mypy issue tracker](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues).

Comment: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14755